# Is it correct: 'the requirement of having done something'?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> The procedure for receiving a passport was simplified: for example, the usual requirement **of having lived for five years** in the country was lifted.

I'm not entirely sure how I should include the information about what that requirement is without introducing a clause that would make my sentence too complicated ('the requirement that the applicants must have lived [...]').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct, and natural, as it is now.

You could also use "The procedure for receiving a passport was simplified; for example, the 5 years' residence requirement was lifted." (or was eliminated).

I prefer a semicolon to a colon between the two independent clauses, since it's the standard way of relating two complete sentences. I think the colon would still be considered correct in this case, and is more common.